# Is safe to not await inside a using block?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

In this code, is it safe to **not** await the `CopyToAsync` or the stream could be disposed before the actual copy is done?

```
public Task SaveAsync(Stream source, string filepath)
{
    using (var file = File.OpenWrite(filepath))
    {
        return source.CopyToAsync(file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not safe, if you don't await then `file` will be disposed before the copy operation completes.